# Update columns in sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am developing one application in that I have to update some columns ,I wrote syntax for update query but it show syntax error please tell me my where I mistake

my update query

```
 public String  updateEntry(UserDetailsDTO userDetails)
 {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     Cursor cur= myDB.rawQuery("UPDATE "+UserDBHandler.USER_TABLE+" SET 
             "+UserDBHandler.DOOR_NUMBER+" = '"+userDetails.getDoorNo()
                             +","+UserDBHandler.LANDMARK+" = 
             '"+userDetails.getLandMark()+","+UserDBHandler.STREET+" = 
              '"+userDetails.getStreet()+
                             ","+UserDBHandler.CITY+" =  
       '"+userDetails.getCity()+","+UserDBHandler.STATE+" = '"+userDetails.getState()+"'   
       WHERE "+ 
                               UserDBHandler.USER_NAME+" = ?",new 
      String[]{userDetails.getUserName()});
     if(cur.moveToFirst()){

        UserDetailsDTO comb_off_job = new UserDetailsDTO();

                comb_off_job.setDoorNo(cur.getString
                (cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserDBHandler.DOOR_NUMBER)));

                comb_off_job.setLandMark(cur.getString
                (cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserDBHandler.LANDMARK)));

                comb_off_job.setStreet(cur.getString
                (cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserDBHandler.STREET)));

                comb_off_job.setCity(cur.getString
                (cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserDBHandler.CITY)));

                comb_off_job.setState(cur.getString
                (cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(UserDBHandler.STATE)));
        sb.append(comb_off_job);
     }

    return sb.toString(); 
 }
```

In my activity

```
userDetailsdto.setDoorNo(doorNumber);
userDetailsdto.setLandMark(Landmark);
userDetailsdto.setStreet(Street);
userDetailsdto.setCity(City);
userDetailsdto.setState(State);
userDetailsdto.setUserName(uName);
userDetalidImpl.updateEntry(userDetailsdto);
```

Comment: Try update(),refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,android.content.ContentValues,java.lang.String,java.lang.String[])

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: post your syntax error trace

Comment: 02-13 12:07:24.133: E/AndroidRuntime(556): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "hiyath": syntax error: , while compiling: UPDATE TABLE_USER SET door_number = '123-12,landmark = 'hiyath,street = 'Manaram,city = 'hyderabad,state = 'ANDRA' WHERE username = ?

Comment: is it right my query?

Comment: you missing some " ' "

Comment: You are missing `'` at end of every `SET`, Just Replace `","` with `"',"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have Syntax error as per Manju Zi say missing ' in query.

```
Cursor cur= myDB.rawQuery("UPDATE "+UserDBHandler.USER_TABLE+" SET 
             "+UserDBHandler.DOOR_NUMBER+" = '"+userDetails.getDoorNo()
                             +","+UserDBHandler.LANDMARK+" = 
             '"+userDetails.getLandMark()+","+UserDBHandler.STREET+" = 
              '"+userDetails.getStreet()+
                             ","+UserDBHandler.CITY+" =  
       '"+userDetails.getCity()+","+UserDBHandler.STATE+" = '"+userDetails.getState()+"'   
       WHERE "+ 
                               UserDBHandler.USER_NAME+" = ?",new 
      String[]{userDetails.getUserName()});
```

check this.
may it help you

```
 Cursor cur= myDB.rawQuery("UPDATE "+UserDBHandler.USER_TABLE+" SET "
                 +UserDBHandler.DOOR_NUMBER+" = '"+userDetails.getDoorNo()+"'"
                                 +","+UserDBHandler.LANDMARK+" = '"+userDetails.getLandMark()+"'"+","+UserDBHandler.STREET+" = '"+userDetails.getStreet()+"'"+
                                 ","+UserDBHandler.CITY+" =  '"+userDetails.getCity()+"'"+","+UserDBHandler.STATE+" = '"+userDetails.getState()+"' WHERE "+ 
                                   UserDBHandler.USER_NAME+" = ?",new 
          String[]{userDetails.getUserName()});
```

Answer (score 2):

check this updated code:

```
Cursor cur= myDB.rawQuery("UPDATE " + UserDBHandler.USER_TABLE + 
            " SET" + UserDBHandler.DOOR_NUMBER + " = '" + userDetails.getDoorNo() + "' ," 
                + UserDBHandler.LANDMARK + " = '" + userDetails.getLandMark() + "' ,"
                + UserDBHandler.STREET + " = '" + userDetails.getStreet() + "' ,"
                + UserDBHandler.CITY + " = '" + userDetails.getCity() + "',"
                + UserDBHandler.STATE + " = '" + userDetails.getState() + "' WHERE " 
                + UserDBHandler.USER_NAME + " = ?",new 
     String[]{userDetails.getUserName()});
```

PS: Amol Sawant 96 Kuli was quicker